# Let $f(x)$ be a function whose third derivative exists and $f(x)=0$ has n distinct real roots in the interval $[a,b]$

Tags: functions, derivatives

State with proof whether the given statement is true or false,

*Statement :*
$$
\frac{d}{d x}\left(f(x) f^{\prime}(x) f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right)
$$ has $3n-4$ distinct real roots in $[a,b]$.

I have tried to solve this problem by Rolle's theorem therefore no of real distinct roots of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are $n-1$ and $n-2$ respectively, their sum with n gives $3n-3$, therefore the derivative of the function in the statement should have $3n-4$ roots, but the answer given is false.
Please rectify my error and provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As $f(x)=0$ has $n$ distinct zeros, $f'(x)=0$ will have $n-1$ distinct roots, $f''(x)=0$ will have $n-2$ distinct roots.
then $g(x)=f(x)f'(x)f''(x)$ will be zero $n+n-1+n-2=3n-3$ times. So by Rolle's Theorem $g'(x)=0$ will have $3n-4$ real distinct  roots.

Comment: Is it clear that the roots of $f''$ and $f$ must be distinct?

Comment: @davidlowryduda Yes, as $f(x)=0$ has distinct real roots, so the roots of $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ will also be distinct.

Comment: After applying Rolle's theorem no of roots should be reduced to 3n-4, how will it increase to 3n-2 please explain